# IntelliJ IDEA build extremely slow with JDK 11 on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, java-11

For several weeks, our development team has been suffering from very slow build times in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 on MacOS since switching from JDK 8 to JDK 11. Build times for a full build went up from ~5 min. to ~20 min.

Answer (score 5):

Found this workaround in the comments of bug ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201978 which is working for us, I'm posting it here as you won't find it via Google for whatsoever reason.

> As a temporary workaround please add the following to IDEA VM options:
>   `-Dcompiler.ref.index=false`
>   and restart IDEA.

Comment: That's correct, same here. Try using JDK 12 with IntelliJ 2019, the problem seems to occur with JDK 11 only.